# Apache GeoIP redirect to page with question mark

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rules, geoip

I have a stumbling block with GeoIP redirect (Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS))

.htaccess has the mandatory directives (necessary for functionality, change can break the whole site)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

so when I add to .htaccess a GeoIP rule like

```
RewriteCond "%{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE}" ^DE$
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ http://de.example.com/info.html$1 [L]
```

it works fine, but when I want to setup a similar redirect to a page with translation

```
RewriteCond "%{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE}" ^DE$
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ http://de.example.com/?lang=de$1 [L]
```

I have error "too many redirects".

Disable GeoIP in .htaccess and go directly to http://de.example.com/?lang=de - all OK.

Already spent few hours playing around syntax but still can't catch what's wrong, so thx for any idea to try !

Comment: _Aside:_ The `$1` backreference in both your examples is always empty and serves no purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you don't want to do an external redirect that exposes your internal URL to clients. All you want (presumably) is to detect GEOIP country and based on that add a query parameter with same country code. You need to add a negated condition to stop rewrite when `lang=` query parameter is already present.

You may try this code in your .htaccess:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond "%{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE}" ^DE$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang= [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(index\.php)?$ $0?lang=de [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Just EXCELLENT ! Thx, you saved my day ! Very right answer even better than I was trying to implement !